# Scene с двумя сегвеями на одном View

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Только начал исследовать Storyboard. У меня на одном View две кнопки, от каждой идет сегвей на один и тот же сториборд но с разными сценариями. Если я правильно понял то в IB я задаю выбранным сегвеям identifier (например seg1, seg2) а потом пишу в коде

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"seg1"]) {
// первый сценарий
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"seg2"]) {
// второй сценарий
    }
}
```

Это верно? Если нет то как это реализовать?

Благодарю за дельный совет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ сам. В топе указан верный вариант. В if потом прописывается:

```
 NextViewController *next = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Также не забывать импортить NextViewController.h во View из которого мы идем. Благодаря этому появляется возможность передавать данныев следующий контроллер.

Comment: да, верно =)